# How to block URL for Google via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to block in the htaccess URL file (https://www.example.com/files/example/index.html) for Google robots. Searching through the search engine I found something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond% {HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteRule ^. * $ "Http \: \ / \ / yordomain \ .com" [R = 301, L]
```

This file is for the domain, and I want to block a specific URL, how can I save it?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use it in htaccess??
Try using `robots.txt` Place the file with the code in the `public_html` folder.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /path/to/the/page/rate
```

Else you can make an, `.htaccess` file and save it in the `public_html` folder.

Check this post [How to block Googlebot from accessing one specific page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102709/how-to-block-googlebot-from-accessing-one-specific-page)

Comment: I have saved a url in robots.txt but googlebot visits this page that's why I want to block it via htaccess.

Comment: Could you post your robots.txt because it should be working.. And the path where you have placed the robots.txt file.

Comment: https://www.example.com/robots.txt - place of robots.txt      
User-agent: *
Disallow: /files/example/

Comment: You're missing a * at the end, to include everything in the folder. `Disallow: /files/example/*` https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt?csw=1

Comment: Thanks. I added * to robots.txt and in this page what you sent me is the address: RewriteRule ^blocked\.php - [F] so for my example my url (path) how it should look like?